# How to persist line numbers option in Kate?

Tags: kde-plasma-5, kate

Pressing F11 will only enable line numbers for the current session, how do I make Kate remember this option?

*The answer given to the question with the title "How to make Kate remember to always show line numbers?" is no longer relevant as the option does no longer exist.*

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I didn't have enough rep to embed the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Settings>Configure Kate>Editor Component>Appearance>Borders>Show line numbers` seems to do it for me (KDE5) (in other words, check the `Borders` tab in the screenshot above).